# Dependencies of Third Party Libraries In Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1.7, third-party-library

Recently I installed `Mpdf` library using composer in my Magento 2.1.7 local setup, and It is working perfect on localhost. Now I have to move those libraries to live server (*I can not install there through composer as I don't have permission.*) for that I have moved `mpdf` directory from `magentoRoot/vendor/mpdf` at same path on live, but it is not working on live server and throwing below error

> Uncaught Error: Class 'Mpdf\Mpdf' not found

After moving files I have ran `setup:upgrade` and `content:deploy` commands.
What I am missing here?  Is there any other changes needed along with moving the library files?

Comment: Did you check vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php? Magento 2 need to recognize your library through autoload.

Comment: @SohelRana yes, there was code missing for Mpdf, I added it and ran `content:deploy` command, but error is still there

Comment: @SohelRana thank you for guiding me to the right path, along with `autoload_psr4.php` I have to make changes in `vendor\composer\autoload_static.php` to make it work. Please add your comment as answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php? Magento 2 need to recognize your library through autoload.

Comment: @Piyush glad to hear that it’s working for you.

Comment: @Piyush how did you solve it